# Restarting Spring Web Flow with new model values

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am trying to find a way that if the user restarts the flow the values are not in it.  If you look at my flow below you can see that the user enters data, previews it and then saves it.. after the save the user can go back to enter new data into the input screen but with my current setup the screen shows the pre-data.  how can I clear it on restart?

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

  <var name="customer" class="org.uftwf.domain.Customer"/>

  <view-state id="helloworld" view="input.jsp" model="customer" popup="true">
    <transition on="submit" to="preview" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="thanks" validate="false"/>
  </view-state>

  <view-state id="preview"  model="customer">
    <transition on="cancel" to="helloworld"/>
    <transition on="accept" to="save">
      <evaluate expression="hellowWorldFlowActions.addCustomer(customer)"/>
    </transition>
  </view-state>

  <view-state id="save"  model="customer">
    <transition on="accept" to="thanks"/>
  </view-state>

  <view-state id="thanks">
    <transition on="restart" to="helloworld"/>
  </view-state>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to define a `reset()` method on your `Customer` class and call that in whichever `<view-state>` `<on-entry>` (like "thanks") or `<transition>` ("restart") makes sense.

Comment: I dont think that would work.. if I cancel on the preview page it will not have any valules then

Comment: My first suggestion, that's true. You get the idea, though. Just call the `reset()` method on whichever transition(s) you want to start fresh. (I'll update my answer to account for your cancel case. Obviously I didn't read your whole flow too carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<view-state id="helloworld" view="input.jsp" model="customer" popup="true">
        <on-entry>
                <set name="flowScope.costumer" value="new org.uftwf.domain.Customer()" />
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="submit" to="preview" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="thanks" validate="false"/>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an external redirect to do same flow. Here is an example.

```
<var name="customer" class="org.uftwf.domain.Customer"/>

<view-state id="thanks">
   <transition on="restart" to="doRestart"/>
</view-state>

<end-state id="doRestart" view="externalRedirect:nameOfThisFlow"></end-state>
```